# Is there such a thing as a bare polariton?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, photons, refraction, quasiparticles

When dealing with photons in matter, I have seen it treated in many ways depending on the material, this leads to exciton [polaritons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polariton) (when dealing with electrons and holes), plasmaritons (dealing with plasma density waves) and phonon polaritons (coupling to lattice vibrations), magnon polaritons (to spin waves) and so on. However is there such a thing as just a bare polariton (not related to other quasiparticles)?  In which kind of materials is it relevant? Is it the same as an uncoupled photon?

Would photons in an ideal transparent media with index $n\neq 1 $ be considered polaritons? Or are we always explicitly assuming that if $n\neq1$ photon interact with other quasiparticles so they must be called polariton-[insert quasiparticle here]?

Comment: That would be a photon? Polariton is by definition a hybridized state of a photon with something else.

Comment: @John that is the question. If the word "polariton" can only be followed by another quasiparticle then what's the deal of calling it like that. Why not photon-exciton or photon-phonon?

Comment: Ok I see your point. Then, I believe if anything such "bare" polariton would be exciton-polariton, as the entity which was originally as simply "polariton" by Hopfield.

Answer (score 0):

Term *polariton* was coined in image of term [*polaron*, which is by definition an electron dressed by photon cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaron) - i.e., and excitation of an electron-phonon system:

> A polaron is a quasiparticle used in condensed matter physics to understand the interactions between electrons and atoms in a solid material. The polaron concept was proposed by Lev Landau in 1933[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaron) and Solomon Pekar in 1946[2] to describe an electron moving in a dielectric crystal where the atoms displace from their equilibrium positions to effectively screen the charge of an electron, known as a phonon cloud. This lowers the electron mobility and increases the electron's effective mass.

There is some ambiguity about what is defined as *polariton*, since different fields use this term to denote different things. The definition used in Wikipedia is the one coming from quantum optics and Bragg lattices:

> In physics, polaritons are quasiparticles resulting from strong coupling of electromagnetic waves with an electric or magnetic dipole-carrying excitation.

In this sense polarons and polaritons are different from conduction electrons, holes, plasmons, phonons, magnons, etc. - the latter group represents quasiparticles arizing from quantization of the respective fields, whereas polaritons and polarons are *by definition* composit particles, resulting from the interaction of two (or more) fields.

Comment: Just to be clear are you saying that "polariton" relates to exciton-polaritons unless indicated otherwise?

Comment: @Mauricio no. I am saying that this term might be used with rather different meanings in different fields. An example where Wikipedia should not he taken as a definitive reference.